# Boot a DRBL Live via pxe

Tags: boot, pxe, clonezilla, live-environment

I'm running a [FOG](http://fogproject.org) server and added many hacks to my pxe menu but now I want to add [DRBL Live](http://drbl.sf.net) but it doesn't work

I tried that with this pxe configuration

```
LABEL fog.drbl
    MENU PASSWD $1$b1E5ld/w$nRekAlrkmtRfofb4ZJC7L1
    kernel fog/drbl/live/vmlinuz boot=live config nomodeset vga=785 ip=frommedia nosplash
    append initrd=fog/drbl/live/initrd.img
    MENU LABEL DRBL Live
    TEXT HELP
    Start Live DRBL server with clonezilla live &  clonezilla server options
    ENDTEXT
```

I get `initrd.img` and `vmlinuz` from the iso of DRBL Live and the parameters from the grub configurations in there `$DRBLiso/EFI/boot/grub.cfg`.

When booting to DRBL option I get the following errors :

```
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
dprobe: module swap not found in modules.dep
```

can anyone see what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .. it works like magic !

I added the file `filesystem.squashfs` to my webserver root and modified the thrid line :

```
kernel fog/drbl/live/vmlinuz boot=live config nomodeset vga=785 ip=frommedia nosplash fetch=http://MYWEBSERVERIP/filesystem.squashfs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label DRBL Live
MENU DEFAULT
# MENU HIDE
MENU LABEL DRBL Live (Default settings)
# MENU PASSWD
kernel drbl/live/vmlinuz
append initrd=drbl/live/initrd.img boot=live config nomodeset vga=785 ip=dhcp nosplash netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.91:/var/lib/tftpboot/drbl i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.blacklist=yes
```